# Online course on theoretical electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics, classical-electrodynamics

I'm looking for good online course for an introduction into theoretical electrodynamics. However, it seems that the MIT opencourseware only contains partial lectures for this topic.

Has anyone got a recommendation for me?

Comment: Do you mean something on the level of Jackson? Like this: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9449/

Answer (score 0):

[These](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NOIqhxvZ74&list=PLDDEED00333C1C30E) are not exactly lectures (its just a guy on youtube) but they cover the whole of Introduction to Electrodynamics book by Griffiths (which is an amazing book btw). If you want to learn about QED as well then his next book called Introduction to Elementary Particles covers a bit of QED calculations like scattering amplitudes, Feynman rules and cross sections etc.

Unfortunately I am not currently aware of any online resources for the later book.

Comment: i think what u specified is the only available complete series in electrodynamics even now. it is a pretty decent lecture series.