# Online physics lecture

Tags: electromagnetism, nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, classical-electrodynamics

I'm looking for online courses "video" for **Classical electrodynamics** and **nuclear physics** for undergraduate students ..

do you know where I can find it ?

Comment: Why don't you try Walter Lewin's lectures on MIT Opencourseware ?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9449/2451 and links therein.